# How do I override dismiss() in Dialog ? Android

Tags: android, dialog, listener

I want to do some data checking after `dialog.dismiss()` or `dialog.cancel` is called.

How should I go about doing this?

Are there any overrides, Listener or methods that i can implement to do some action then dismiss the Dialog?

I tried `dialog.setOnDismissListener` but  that dismisses the dialog first then calls this listener.

Comment: Whatever code you write after dialog.dismiss(); it will get executed you don't need any listener i guess

Comment: Why don't you just overwrite `dismiss()` and place your code before or after `super.dismiss()`?

Answer (score 5):

You could create your own custom Dialog with a `DialogFragment` and just overwrite `dismiss()`.

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Build the alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles);
        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        // Do your stuff here
        super.dismiss();
    }

    ...
}
```

Take a look here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: For me this still doesn't work, when I arrive in Dismiss the dialog is already dismissed even before super.dismiss();
NB: I am using Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Hoping it may help if AlertDialog works as Dialog.

I just did this type of coding and got such results:

somewhere in the code:

```
AlertDialog diaBox = myDialog();
                    diaBox.show();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "this time it is 4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Than making "myDialog()" method:

```
private AlertDialog myDialog() {
        AlertDialog myQuittingDialogBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(v_context)
                // set message, title, and icon
                .setTitle("Delete")
                .setMessage("Do you want to delete")

                .setPositiveButton("Delete", (dialog, whichButton) -> {
                    //Any code is possible
                    dialog.dismiss();
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> {
                    //Any code is possible
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "this time it is 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "this time it is 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                })
                .create();

        myQuittingDialogBox.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // Custom actions when the dialog is dismissed
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "this time it is 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return myQuittingDialogBox;
    }
```

And the Toast sequence was like this:
4
Hitting NegativeButton
1
2
3

So everything that I wanted I did in the `public void onDismiss` method and everything worked fine :)

P.S. If you found mistake or know a better solution - PLEASE! write it down and I will edit and fix my code - THANK YOU!

P.P.S. If you will make `dialog.dismiss();` it will always show you that Toast with 3 in it! For now I do not know how to call super `.dismiss()` so it would not show you Toast with 3 in it. But I may update it later :)